# build adobe air to use YouTube API v2.0

Tags: actionscript-3, air, youtube-api

I'm trying to use YouTube API v2.0 to let users authenticate into their YouTube account and be able to upload videos from there... but I want to do this application in AS3 as an adobe air application.

I searched the api but I couldn't find any proof that I can do this with AS3? thought to drop a line here and ask if it's possible at all? specially being able to upload videos through the adobe air desktop app?

If possible, is there any link you could give me to get me started faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/air-youtube-uploader/) appears to be a google code project written in as3 that supports uploading videos in desktop air apps (see the example AirYouTubeUploaderSampleApp).